# Generating a list of figures in Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

How can I generate a table listing all of the images used in a Microsoft Word 2010 document?

Comment: You mean something [like this](http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/word/list_of_figures.gif)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. list of figures!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slhck's link is referring to a table of figures.  Typically, you cite the images and tables you put in a paper.  Look under the Reference tab for the Insert Caption for images and tables.

After you caption everything, you click the **insert Table of Figures** on that same tab.